# Counting letters in txt file

Tags: python, spyder

Hello im trying to write a code that can count letters in a txt file.

I have written a code, but it only counts lower case letters. i have tryed using the lower function, but with no luck

```
import numpy as np

def letterFrequency(filename):
    letters="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    filein = open(filename, "r")
    lines = filein.readlines()
    smalltxt = "".join(lines)
    totalOccurrences=0
    v=[]

    for i in letters:
        occurrences=smalltxt.count(i)
        totalOccurrences=totalOccurrences + occurrences
        v.append(occurrences)

    v=np.array([v])
    freq=(v/totalOccurrences)*100

    return  freq

print(letterFrequency("small_text.txt"))
```

The output of the percantages of a is 7,74%, but the epected output should be 8,1%. 
I believe its because the only counts lower case letters

Comment: you have not used the lower function anywhere in this code

Answer (score 5):

If you want to count alphabets with case-insensitive scheme, just convert all of them to a single case. correction in the line.

```
smalltxt = "".join(lines).lower()
```

should do the job.

Comment: Thanks that solved it, i was confused where i was suppose to use the lower function.